# QT How to convert the text from a file and setCurrentIndex?

Tags: c++, qt

I am opening a config file with simple numbers and words (10 total). I am using setText() and SetValue() on the words and numbers(QLineEdit) with no issues.  I am using a QCombobox to have the user select from the drop down.  I use the currenttext() when I save the config file.  QComboBox uses index (0-4).  When the user selects Open Config file,  I am opening the users config file, reading (inputfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) and reading line from config (line = in.readLine).
QUESTION IS: How do I take the word from in.readline and convert to correct dropdown index number of the QComboBox?

I am only getting the first index (0) of the QcomboBox even though it should be (1-3).

```
QString FileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, 
       "Open Config File...", "", "Text Files(*.txt);;Text Files(*.txt)");
    
    QFileInfo fileInfo(FileName);
    QString filename(fileInfo.fileName());
    
    QFile inputfile(filename);
    if (inputfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly));
        {
    
    QTextStream in(&inputfile);
        
    QString line = in.readLine();
    ui.SourceTer->setCurrentIndex(line.toInt());

    line = in.readLine();
    ui.SourceElev->setCurrentIndex(line.toInt());

    line = in.readLine();
    ui.SourceBath->setCurrentIndex(line.toInt());
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the description, in plain text, of the file contents and format.

Comment: If you're restoring a file that you previously saved with the same program, and the items in the combobox are always the same, then just use `setCurrentText()`, which is the getter function for `currentText()` you're already using. As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop): "if there is a matching text in the list, `currentIndex` is set to the corresponding index".

Comment: @MusicMante - I get an error: "Qcombobox" has no member of "setCurrentText".  This is how I am storing the qcombobox :    outFile.write(line.toAscii());
 line.sprintf("%s\n", ui.SourceTer->currentText().toStdString().c_str());

Answer (score 0):

I guess the probem is you are trying to do `line.toInt()` which results 0 in case your string doesn't represent a number. As musicamante mentioned in the comment, the better approach is to use `ui.SourceBath->setCurrentText(line);`

Comment: I get an error: "Qcombobox" has no member of "setCurrentText". This is how I am storing the qcombobox : outFile.write(line.toAscii()); line.sprintf("%s\n", ui.SourceTer->currentText().toStdString().c_str());

Comment: Which version of Qt do you use? Since at least Qt 5 QComboBox certainly has property called [currentText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop) with related getter, setter and notify signal.

Comment: As of your way to writing the file, you can just call `constData()` method on QString.

Comment: Mike - I am using 4.8.2.  I will look at the constData().

Comment: Qt 4.8.x support ended on 2015. Whats the reason to use such an old version?

Comment: Mike - QT 4.8.2 is what I have for VS2010.  I guess I need to see about downloading newer.  I ended up looking for what is supported under 4.8 and found the following code works perfect for Qcombobox.  line = in.readLine();  int index = ui.SourceTer->findText(line);   ui.SourceTer->setCurrentIndex(index);